# Как перенести данные из URL в input

Tags: javascript, form, input, get

Нужно перенести данные из URL, созданные GET запросом в форму обратной связи. Нашёл код, но он для конкретной ссылки, не пойму, как поменять, чтобы он автоматически брал данные их адресной строки

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<input id="siteurl" type="text"> 
<input id="title" type="text"> 
<input id="description" type="text"> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var url_string = "http://site.ru/edit?url=site.ru/doc1&title=Тут+стьи&description=Описание&user=Admin"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var siteurl = url.searchParams.get("url");
var title = url.searchParams.get("title");
var description = url.searchParams.get("description");

$('#siteurl').val(siteurl);
$('#title').val(title);
$('#description').val(description);

console.log(siteurl,title,description);
</script>
```

Comment: Заменить адрес на `window.location.href`. Это и указано в вашем же коде)

Comment: var url_string = "window.location.href";

Не сработало

Comment: Без кавычек... `var url_string = window.location.href;` — в объекте window найдет объект location, откуда возьмет url-строку href. А `"window.location.href"` с кавычками - это просто ничегонеделающая строка.

Comment: Благодарю. Как отметить ваше решение?

Answer (score 0):

new URL - это экспериментальная технология, поэтому поддержка браузерами сомнительная. А что бы брать адрес из адресной строки - location.href